# Rubyインスタンス変数のキャッシュ保持期間について

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

Rubyインスタンス変数のキャッシュが保持される期間を知りたいです。

```
class Hoge< ActiveRecord::Base
  def hoge
    @hoge =|| Hoge.all
  end
end
```

上記のような@hogeインスタンス変数がキャッシュされていて
どのタイミングでキャッシュが無くなってHoge.allが呼ばれるようになるか知りたいです。
HogeクラスはActiveRecordになります。

Comment: 編集でコードを変更されたようですね。基本的にはそれでよいと思うのですが、今回は既に回答がついており、その回答でコードに言及されています。回答との整合性が心配です。（大筋では整合していると思うのですが、文章的に微妙に噛み合わなくなっている気がします）こういう場合は追記という形で変更部分が分かるようにしていただけると助かります。

Comment: すみません、以後気を付けますm(__)m

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rubyにはインスタンス変数を自動的にキャッシュするような機能はありません。インスタンスが生成されると同時にインスタンス変数も初期化され、インスタンスが破棄されるときにインスタンス変数の内容も破棄されます。キャッシュはされないので、キャッシュの保持期間もありません。

あなたのコード例で言うと、`Hoge`クラスのインスタンス生成直後に`hoge`メソッドを呼べば、必ず`Hoge.all`が呼ばれます。その後、同一のインスタンスに対して`hoge`メソッドを呼んでも(その途中で明示的に`@hoge`の内容をクリアしない限り)`Hoge.all`は呼ばれません。

RailsのActionクラスの場合、インスタンスはリクエスト処理ごとに生成されます。(同じActionクラスで処理されるリクエストが同時に届いた場合、同一Actionクラスのインスタンスが複数生成されます。)
　従って、一つのリクエストの中で最初に(`@hoge`に値が設定される前に)`hoge`を呼んだ場合、`Hoge.all`が呼ばれますが、その後同じリクエスト処理の中で`hoge`を呼んでも`Hoge.all`は実行されません。

ActiveRecordのようなModelクラスの場合、同時に複数のインスタンスが生成されることが多いので話はもうちょっと複雑になりますが、「インスタンス変数は個々のインスタンスがそれぞれ別々に保持している」ことが分かっていれば結局同じことです。

---

*HogeクラスはActiveRecordになります。*
わざわざ追記していただきましたが、上記の通りです。ActiveRecordではクエリー結果やデータベースとの接続に関する状態をキャッシュしていますが、特定のユーザ定義のインスタンス変数の中身をキャッシュすることはありません。
　インスタンス変数ではなく、`Hoge.all`メソッドが何度か呼ばれたときに、2度目からはキャッシュの内容を返す可能性はありますが、これは「インスタンスの集合体」であって、特定のインスタンス変数ではありません。

つまり「`Hoge`クラスはActiveRecord」であっても、「`Hoge`クラスのインスタンス生成直後に`hoge`メソッドを呼べば、必ず`Hoge.all`が呼ばれます。その後、同一のインスタンスに対して`hoge`メソッドを呼んでも`Hoge.all`は呼ばれません。」と言う事情は変わりません。ただ、「インスタンス生成直後」かどうかを一般的に判定はできないので、それに依存したコードを書くべきではないでしょう。

当然ながらインスタンス変数は各インスタンスごとに別個のものですから、`Hoge`クラスのあるインスタンスについては`Hoge.all`が呼ばれて`@hoge`に値が保持されていたとしても、別のインスタンスの`@hoge`は空っぽで、そちらのインスタンスの`hoge`メソッドを呼ぶと`Hoge.all`がまた呼び出される、という可能性はあります。
　そもそも個々のレコードを表すインスタンスがそれぞれ別個に全てのレコードを持つというのが変だと思うのですが。

Comment: HogeクラスはActiveRecordなのですがインスタンス変数が保持されることなく呼ばれる度にインスタンス変数が生成されるということでしょうか？

Comment: Hogeクラスのインスタンスが生成されるたびに、それぞれのインスタンスの中にインスタンス変数が生成・初期化されると言うことです。(ActiveRecordのキャッシュを無視すれば)hogesテーブルに100件のレコードがあれば、Hogeクラスのインスタンスは100個生成され、そのそれぞれがインスタンス変数を持つことになります。

Comment: 丁寧な説明ありがとうございます。理解が悪くて申し訳ないのですが
一つのリクエストで@hogeインスタンス変数に値が入ったとしても次のリクエストでは同じインスタンスが使われるとは限らず別のインスタンスになる可能性があるということでしょうか？
もしくは「インスタンス生成直後」で無いと同じインスタンスが使われることは無いということでしょうか？

Comment: というのもHogeにレコードを追加すると@hogeに保持された値では無く、レコードが追加されたものが表示される動作になっているからです。(動作としてはそちらのほうがいいのですが)

Comment: 「一つのリクエストで@hogeインスタンス変数に値が入ったとしても次のリクエストでは同じインスタンスが使われるとは限らず別のインスタンスになる可能性があるというこ‌​とでしょうか？」→yesです。

Comment: インスタンスが同じになるとは限らず、また、GCでオブジェクトが消えている可能性もあるということですね。何となく理解できました、ありがとうございます。